# oracle regex replace (keep only a-z)

Tags: regex, oracle

I have data in `last_name` column.

This data comes from online and at times users are copy pasting the last name from a word document.  This is a problem when a last name has a single quote.  Somehow the single quote from a word document is weird.

I want to write an oracle regex replace in my select query such a way that it replaces everything in the `last_name` column but just keeps (a-z or A-Z).

Is this doable?

Comment: What happens if the last name is D'Angelo? You will need to be careful with your regex.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that.  I'd rather have it converted to DAngelo instead, for now. This has to be in place until we start catching this up front before it is submitted into the DB.

Answer (score 12):

finally I went with this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(mbr_last_name,'[^a-zA-Z'']','') replaced_last_name
```

I'm keeping a to z A to Z and a single quote

Comment: You could probably go with regexp_replace(mbr_last_name,'[^[:alpha:]'']'), just to be a little more concise.

Answer (score 2):

By 'weird' do you mean that it is not the normal single quote?  Word has some really stupid characters that it uses by default (called '[Smart quotes](http://www.google.co.nz/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=s&hl=en&source=hp&q=word+smart+quotes&meta=&btnG=Google+Search) (google)'. which look a bit like the standard quotes but have different behaviour when converting to and from ASCII and for example UTF-8

To identify them in SQL do a select using the function ASCIISTR and look for a sub-string in the form `<backslash><4 digits>`  (This works with a DB with UTF-8 and simialr characters, I'm unsure about its return in a database with ASCII NLS parameters)

```
select asciistr(COLUMN) from table
```

I have used the following code to remove them in some recent work I have been doing

```
update jiraissue
set summary = replace(asciistr(summary), '\2013','-')
where asciistr(summary) like '%\2013%';`)
```

HTH

Comment: thanks. i did not know about the asciistr function.  I don't know whether it is smart quote or not but it shows as a little square in oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regexp_replace operator for instance:

```
select regexp_replace('foobar1000!!!!','[[:cntrl:]]|[[[:digit:]]|[[:punct:]]') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('FOOBAR1000!!!!','[[:CNTRL:]]|[[[:DIGIT:]]|[[:PUNCT:]]') 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
foobar
```

Comment: I like the thought of regexp_replace, but this will miss control characters and spaces and such.. I would go with something like:

select regexp_replace('foo Bar1000!!!!','[^[:alpha:]]') from dual;

Comment: It won't miss control characters [[:cntrl:]] matches non printing control characters, [[:punct:]] matches punctuation and [[:digit:]] matches digits.

Answer (score 0):

Worthwhile looking at the CONVERT function, which will do a conversion between character sets. You can convert to 'plain' 7-bit ASCII characters to remove anomalies.

For example

> select convert('êê','US7ASCII') from
>   dual;